# Resources on Solving Convex Optimization Problems in the Compressed Sensing Field

Tags: optimization, compressive-sensing, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, books

When I read papers of compressed sensing, sparse representation and whatever requiring optimization of a cost function, I just find the final results as an iterative equation or so which will converge after few iterations and solve the problem.

But, when I try to add some other constraints to the cost function, I cannot derive the iterative or whatever the solution is and I know that is for my poor mathematics.

Can anyone lead me to a book or so to read and understand how to solve these types of mathematics? What book chapter? What tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few options:

1. [Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe - Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).
   This is the classic in this field. Very well written book.
   Also have a look on other papers of Boyd on similar subjects such as the The [Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers (ADMM)](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html).
   They also have a great [MOOC Course Stanford Online CVX 101 - Convex Optimization](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CVX101/Winter2014/about).
2. [Amir Beck - Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization - Theory, Algorithms and Applications](https://sites.google.com/site/amirbeck314/books) & [Amir Beck - First-Order Methods in Optimization](https://sites.google.com/site/amirbeck314/books).
   Amir is a great teacher and his book are both deep, practical and easy to read.
3. [CMU Statistics 36-725 - Convex Optimization: Fall 2016](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F16/) by [Ryan Tibshirani](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/).
   [Videos are available on YouTube](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F16/).

I think once you skim through those you'll be able to handle most of the cases in Convex Optimization.